# Xamarin: How to Reference a ScrollView Inside OnPageFinished?

Tags: android, class, user-interface, xamarin.android, scrollview

I'm trying to listen for a WebView finishing LoadUrl using OnPageFinished inside a WebViewClient class and then fire ScrollTo on a ScrollView.  The code compiles but my app crashes when it loads, and there's no exception thrown in debug.

```
public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);

        Activity _whatsOnActivity = new WhatsOnActivity();

        ScrollView _view = _whatsOnActivity.FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.scrollView66);

        _view.ScrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}
```

and here's how my Activity looks:

```
[Activity]
public class WhatsOnActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.whatsOn);

        WebView whatsOnWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewWhatsOn);

        MyWebViewClient instance = new MyWebViewClient();

        whatsOnWebView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);

        whatsOnWebView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        whatsOnWebView.LoadUrl("https://www.bitchute.com/#listing-subscribed");
        whatsOnWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        whatsOnWebView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        whatsOnWebView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
        whatsOnWebView.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

The whole project can be found here: 
https://github.com/hexag0d/bitchute_mobile_android_a2

Answer (score 0):

> XAMARIN: How to Reference a ScrollView Inside OnPageFinished?

Add a contruct method for your `MyWebViewClient` could resolve this issue:

```
public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    private WhatsOnActivity whatsOnActivity;

    public MyWebViewClient(WhatsOnActivity whatsOnActivity)
    {
        this.whatsOnActivity = whatsOnActivity;
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {

        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);

        //Activity _whatsOnActivity = new WhatsOnActivity();

        ScrollView _view = whatsOnActivity.FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.scrollView1);

        _view.ScrollTo(0, 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!  that worked to stop the app from crashing.  However, my ScrollTo does nothing.  Do you happen to know if I'm using it correctly in that example?  I appreciate the help.